# jQuery Extends - Need to merge object and array

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I have an array that I want to merge with an object in JavaScript! The object is something like this:

```
{fv:"",sv:"",tv:"",ffv:""}
```

...and the array is something like this:

```
["fv", "sv", "tv", "ffv"]
```

What I want is a merge of the two (something like a hash) like so:

```
{fv: "fv", sv:"sv", tv:"tv", ffv: "ffv"}
```

So far this is the jQuery I have come up with but it is off (it just increments the indices of a new object and assigns each of the items there and keeps the original objects values...I want to merge the two like a hash!)

```
$.extend({fv:"",sv:"",tv:"",ffv:""}, ["fv", "sv", "tv", "ffv"] );
```

Comment: It's a little ambiguous what you're wanting to do with your merge. Are you always wanting to populate the object with the values of the array being used for both the property and value?

Comment: My apologies! Yes, I want that object populated with the array but I'm going to statically set the object properties. Basically I want the values of the object (which might be unknown) but I know I want property 1 from array position 1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a regular loop will suffice:

```
var obj = {fv:"",sv:"",tv:"",ffv:""};
var items = ["fv", "sv", "tv", "ffv"];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    obj[item] = item;
}
```

Comment: Should be `var items = ["fv", "sv", "tv", "ffv"]`

Comment: my apologies but the arrays items are not going to actually correlate to the objects sources, so i don't think using obj[item] would actually work. i might get something like obj = {fv: "", sv: "", tv: "", ffv: ""} and the array could be arr= ["ha", "hahah", "hahahahah", "test"]. these are obviously example values but it demonstrates my post.

Comment: The problem is that the object properties are not ordered. You could loop through the object properties with a `for..in` loop, but the ordering is somewhat arbitrary and may even differ across browsers if you're running this in a web browser.